# Is there a way to remove shadows of piechart of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, chart

Is there a way to remove shadows of piechart of GeoServer (Eastwood library)? GeoServer always makes shadow in piechart, while the original [Google piechart API](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts) does not have shadow.

[image]

Note: The piecharts in the map above are created with 2 rules, each with a piechart `<sld:ExternalGraphic>`.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the tutorial from 
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/pretty_maps/charting.html

it seems that there is no place in the SLD for removing the shadow. However, the pie chart type "cht=p3 3D (flat) Pie" may look a bit better than the "cht=p". You can write to geoserver-users and ask if it would make sense to make a feature request. The latest version of Eastwood Charts is from 2008 http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/ which makes be doubtful.